# raphael.2.1.0.min.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to run the [justgage](http://justgage.com/) plugin on my Rails 4 app, but I'm getting this error:

```
raphael.2.1.0.min.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
```

This is all I added to my **application.js**:

```
//= require justgage.1.0.1
//= require raphael.2.1.0.min
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Raphael from [here](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/releases/tag/v2.1.0) and it should work. By your link it really has some issues.